# how to put in a param even if the value of param is null

Tags: karate

so my code is as follows:

```
* def value = newMP.response.data[randomizer].phoneNumber
* def nullvalue = 'null'
* def filter = (value == '#null' ? nullvalue : value)
* print filter
And param filter[phoneNumber] = filter
```

The result of this code is
[image]

Thing is that my application allows a search for null as well. therefore im looking if its possible to put in a filter that is null based on the conditional logic

Additionally if i go like this

```
And param filter[phoneNumber] = 'null'
```

the null value is in the GET call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes by default Karate ignores null-valued params and this is what most users expect.

You have not been clear as to what you are expecting but I'm guessing you need a param with an empty value.

Try this:

```
And param filter = ''
```

Also read this example for more ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding.

what i wanted was the param value to be either `null` or `'null'` and then validate the response has `null` (Not the string form)

I did a work around and put it as a separate answer. please mark it is good if you agree with it

Answer (score 1):

What i required was to put in the value of the parameter as either `null` or `"null"`, and the validate in response that the value is `null`, not the string form of it. below is the workaround for it.

```
And def value = newMP.response.data[randomizer].phoneNumber
And eval if (value == null) karate.set('value', 'null')
And param filter[phoneNumber] = value
When method GET
Then status 200
* eval if (value == 'null') karate.set('value', null)
Then match response.data[0].attributes.phoneNumber contains value
```

Comment: cool. everything looks good except the `And param filter[phoneNumber] = value` - does it really do what you expect ?